# Generate object code from json in objective c

Tags: objective-c, json, object

I need to convert json to objective-c object. I mean not parse it in code, but generate the code of the object by some json. Are there some tools for it? I know how to do it in java([jsonpojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)).

Also i wonder if there is a certain way to automatically store data from json to a real objective-c Object without manual parsing.

In Java its done by Gson library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are describing exactly what ROAD iOS Framework. Take a look: https://github.com/epam/road-ios-framework

The tool for generating plain model classes from JSON is [ROADClassesGenerator](https://github.com/epam/road-ios-framework/tree/master/tools/ROADClassesGenerator) and if you will use ROAD for networking then serialization into generated classes comes for free.

One note, it's not actively supported now, due to pervasiveness of Swift and the fact if its tight reliance on macros which are still poorly supported in Swift, but it's still work and do the job nevertheless.